# "Diff" Two Different DataFrames by Index and keep only "new"/"different"/"removed"

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing two CSV files with the format DATE, NAME, TYPE, CODE

There is a row per day, per name, and per type for all of my users and all 365 days in the year and two types.

So I have 2017-01-01, Bob, A, 1 2017-01-01, Bob, B, 1 2017-01-01, Steve, A, 1 2017-01-01, Steve, B, 1 2017-01-02, Bob, A, 1 2017-01-02, Bob, B, 1 2017-01-02, Steve, A, 1 2017-01-02, Steve, B, 1 ...

What I would like to do is take two CSVs and compare each row such that for each  = Value the resulting set only has that  IFF the values differ (and keep the value from the second one).  I'd also like to keep the "new" and "deleted" values and know which is which.

Is there an easy way to do that in Pandas or do I need to iterate?

-Eric

Comment: What do you mean by changing? Row in same position in file or row with same DATE and NAME? What is a criteria this is same row but changed ?

Comment: Please create two dummy dataframes and show the expected results in the question.  Please see [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).